# scp file to server with user different than ssh login

Tags: scp, file-copy, chown

I need to copy file `somefile.jar` from local computer (cygwin) to remote `server.local`. I have an ssh login `corp` to `server.local` that a sudoer on `server.local`. I need to place the file to folder `/opt/alice/libs/` owned by another user:

```
[corp@server.local ~]$ ls -ld /opt/alice/libs
drwxr-xr-x 2 alice alice 12288 Apr 13 11:09 /opt/alice/libs
```

I cannot direct upload file to chosen directory because of insufficient rights. So, my way to copy has few steps with `/tmp/` on `server.local`

```
$ scp ./somefile.jar corp@server.local/tmp/
$ ssh copr@server.local
Last login: Thu Apr 12 18:05:41 2018 from 192.168.87.34

[corp@server.local ~]$ sudo chown alice:alice /tmp/somefile.jar
[corp@server.local ~]$ sudo -u alice mv /tmp/somefile.jar /opt/alice/libs/
```

Is there a shorter way to perform the upload?

---

If a tool does not exist to achieve my purposes, maybe it is possible to make a `*.sh` script that include all of these operations?

Comment: If you can't connect as alice to the server, then yes, you found the shortest way to do that

Comment: @Félicien - Thank you. I cannot login as `alice` user

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a simple script, assuming your sudo does not need a password, you could pipe the data across:

```
tar cf - ./somefile.jar | 
ssh -t copr@server.local sudo -u alice tar xf - -C /opt/alice/libs/
```

The `-C` changes directory before extracting the file. If your tar does not have this, add an explicit `cd /opt/alice/libs/` first.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely the only way to do that.